# Can I use a shell other than cmd with IdeaVim

Tags: windows, shell, pycharm, ideavim

I'm using IdeaVim with PyCharm 2021.2  on Windows 10.   I've found that `!!` commands seem to use the DOS `cmd` command prompt to execute shell commands. I'd like to invoke Cygwin/bash or git bash (or maybe use the WSL?)

I haven't been able to find any obvious settings in PyCharm.

You can change the terminal settings but that doesn't seem to affect IdeaVim.  And I can't find an settings for the plug-in other than the key conflict map.

I've tried setting it in `.ideavimrc`, but that doesn't seem to work. I know the settings should be ok, because I test them `vim -u .ideavimrc` and they work for `vim`, but not idea vim.

After a while it occurred to me to look use use the normal vim settings.  Duh.

But that doesn't seem to work.  I know the config is ok in general because it is effective for my vim with -u .ideavimrc.  But it just
breaks !! in IdeaVim.  I just get an error sound.

If you use `:set all` in IdeaVim you set the `shellxquote=(`   is set.   Unsetting in `.ideavimrc` has no effect, neither does using `:set shellxquote=`  in IdeaVim.   Are the some more obscure vimrc setting to try.   How much vim is in IdeaVim?

Has anyone figured out what the secret sauce is?   Surely someone is using IdeaVim with a different shell for external commands.

Answer (score 2):

If you [install WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install), this works in IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1 ([source](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-2517)), which *should* work in PyCharm too (since PyCharm is IDEA but with only 1 paid plugin: namely Python).

1. click the IdeaVim icon (lower-right corner) > `open ~/.ideavim`
2. add `set shell=bash.exe`
3. add set `shellcmdflag=-c` (most common case) OR `set shellcmdflag=-lic` (l=login shell, i=interactive shell, c=run the commands in step 5)
4. restart your IDE OR enter this Ex command: `source c:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\.ideavimrc`
5. enter this Ex command `!ls -lah`